# Codeigniter 2.1 - Security for the admin part of the web site

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have following measures to secure admin part:

- Inside session I have following parts:

**is_logged_in** -> This can be 0 or 1

**admin** -> checks if the user is admin or not (values are 0 or 1)

And before any function inside admin controller or controller that have something to do with administration of the web site I call function to check if the user is logged in and is he an administrator? Is this enough? If it is not, what can I do to make admin part more secure?

Comment: Not an answer, but maybe useful for you: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819275/what-is-the-best-practice-for-restricting-specific-pages-to-logged-in-users-only

Comment: so you set these only once & check it on every page? If that's what you're doing, then it's not secure. You'll have to pull these values from a database (store the session in db & query to make sure that session_id() == $db->session_id, and make sure you retrieve the is_admin flag from db also) this way you can kick the user out anytime you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple form of session is

```
$data = array(
    "admin" => $username,
    "is_logged_in"  => true
);
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

But you can store in session also the id (if you need it) or something else.

And if you want to check it, you can do it like this

```
if (!isset($this->session->userdata['admin'])) {
    redirect('admin/login'); // for example
}
```

I prefer to store in DB the Session.

For more, read
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 2):

You should check out Phil Sturgeon's blog post [here](https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2010/02/08/CodeIgniter-Base-Classes-Keeping-it-DRY/)

When you have an entire section that requires separate authentication, extending the CI_Controller will save you a lot of code and make things much cleaner.